# Is there a difference between numpy NPV and excel NPV?

Tags: python, excel, numpy

I have excel in which there is a row with 11 values in it.

```
TotalSavings = [0, 8000, 8000, 8000, 8000, 8000, 8000, 8000, 8000, 8000, 8000]
```

with the discount rate of 0.08, I calculated the NPV in excel using =`NPV(0.08, TotalSavings)` (obviously there were 11 columns so instead of TotalSavings there is C3:C14(here C3 is 0 value and C14 is 8000)). Its was **49704**.
And when I did the same thing with numpy NPV.

```
print(np.npv(0.08, TotalSavings))
```

Result was: **53680**.
Can someone please help? I want the same result as we are getting in excel.

Comment: please se the updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems one uses beginning of period *payments* and the other uses end of period payments.

numpy's formula is

```
(values / (1+rate)**np.arange(0, len(values))).sum(axis=0)
```

Changing it to

```
(values / (1+rate)**np.arange(1, len(values)+1)).sum(axis=0)
```

produces the same value you get with excel.

---

- The [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.npv.html) show the summation from t=0 to M-1.

  [image]
- [Excel docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/npv-function-8672cb67-2576-4d07-b67b-ac28acf2a568) shows a summation from i=1 to n

  [image]

---

For excel this makes the denominator larger for each term in the summation resulting in a smaller sum.